# Differences between hammer curl and a regular curl

Tags: biceps, curls

What is the difference between a hammer curl and a regular curl? I understand the form differences. I'm looking for an anatomical answer.

More specifically, what differences in muscle groups (in the bicep) does a hammer curl and a regular curl workout?

Are there specific benefits between executing a hammer curl and a regular curl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hammer curls are supposed to target the [brachioradialis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachioradialis) and [brachialis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachialis_muscle) muscles more directly than a standard curl due to pronation.

Answer (score 1):

My perception is that the hammercurl builds the width off the bicep as supposed to the regular curl. i do them infront of my chest and never higher than a 90 degree angle. if you go higher you target different muscles.

Comment: Note from the future: it doesn't target different muscles, but once you've passed 90deg it's less *efficient* because the lever is reduced. That's one reason people like bent-over curls; gravity can work at full effectiveness through a larger range of motion.